# Not able to install the wxPython 4.2.0 library,python version 3.11

Tags: python, wxwidgets

Please check the error below, my python version is `3.11`.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install wxPython
Collecting wxPython
  Using cached wxPython-4.2.0.tar.gz (71.0 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [8 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wvjzqe_a\wxpython_68bc31ed61f445a3971064110725d233\setup.py", line 27, in <module>
          from buildtools.config import Config, msg, opj, runcmd, canGetSOName, getSOName
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wvjzqe_a\wxpython_68bc31ed61f445a3971064110725d233\buildtools\config.py", line 30, in <module>
          from attrdict import AttrDict
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'attrdict'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I just really need this library, I don't know what to do.

Comment: Try it out. Create a virtual environment with the "python -m venv venv" command, then activate it with ".\venv\Scripts\activate", then manually install "attrdict" with "pip install attrdict", then install wxPython with "pip install wxPython".

Comment: Thank you, but it fixed 1 out of 3 errors, here are some more errors: "error: subprocess-exited-with-error" and "error: metadata-generation-failed", I will be glad if you help again.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the new problem

Answer (score 2):

Try to:
go to directory of your Python e.g C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\attrdict
and edit files:
**mixins.py , mapping.py , merge.py , default.py**
by changing line:

```
from collections import Mapping
```

to

```
from collections.abc import Mapping
```

Then Install requests:

```
pip install requests
```

Then try to instal again wxPython by:

```
pip install wxPython
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a package called attrdict which is a dependency as shown in the error, please try this `pip3 install attrdict` and then install wxPython

Comment: Thank you, but it fixed 1 out of 3 errors, here are some more errors: "error: subprocess-exited-with-error" and "error: metadata-generation-failed", I will be glad if you help again.